# telegram doesn't show the image preview link always

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I use the following code to send a message that contains both text and image. in order to show the image i used link preview to show the images, but almost every 15 message, 2 of them have no image preview whereas their image link is shown by browser (i mean no problem with the link) and the rest of the messages show both text and image preview with no problem. where is the problem?

```
<?php


$message = the message
$img = img_link

$message_="
<a href='$img'>&#8205;</a>
$message
";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botToken.'/sendMessage');
$data = array(
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'text' => $message_,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'disable_web_page_preview' => false,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res=curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Telegram caches link previews. Have you considered telling telegram to update the cache? If not try.

There is official Telegram bot @Webpagebot. Add it, send a /updatepreview command and send up to 10 links to this bot. The link preview (title, description and badge) will be updated shortly.